# Git Force Remote Branch

Tags: git

We currently have two branches: master and pre_updated_site. We developed a new version of a site and released it to production, but it appears to have had some adverse affects on user behavior.

As a result we created a branch from an old commit - prior to these new code changes:
git checkout XXXLONGCOMMITIDXXXX -b pre_updated_branch

We'd like to force this branch into the remote server so we can observe user behavior - however I can't seem to get the site to updated with a forced push:
git push remote_server pre_updated_branch:master --force

We'd like to keep the updates in the commit history for now until we decide how the old site performs against the new one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some information about how "the website" ends up on your web server after pushing something onto a git branch is required to help you.

Comment: " I can't seem to get the site to updated with a forced push" -- what happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try merging your `pre_updated_branch` onto `master` on your local, and then pushing your `master` branch to `remote_server`?

Maybe there are some problems with merging that you may be able to resolve locally.